# Measuring Noise and Ripple using multimeter

Tags: power-supply

I would like to do a noise and ripple measurement using a simple DMM. Is there a circuit which I can add on to capture the peak-peak noise and ripple, feeding the output into a multimeter ?

Comment: You're going to have to give us a little more information than that.

Comment: Such as over what bandwidth, what is the fundamental frequency of the ripple, what waveshape are you expecting the ripple to be, do you want peak or rms values etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a thing is readily available.

You are looking at building something like an AC amplifer followed by (positive and negative) peak detectors, with a decay time of several seconds to allow a DMM to read the result reasonably accurately.

It's not particularly difficult problem but without knowing more, I don't think you'll get a more specific answer.

At least "peak detector circuit"  gives you a search term to help you find solutions.